# Ubuntu 18.04 TLS - apt-get update - The repository security.ubuntu.com no longer has a Release file

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Ubuntu 18.04 should be supported till april 2028

apt-get update

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                     
Ign:2 https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                    
Err:5 https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release
  404  NOT FOUND [IP: 91.189.88.181 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

lsb_release -a;

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't use any external repositories like ppa.launchpad.net etc
The official repository doesn't work http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

I've checked on my other servers, it also doesn't work. Is anybody else experiencing this issue?

Comment: Hmmm. Following the URL, the Release file is indeed there; it exists in the expected location. However, it's only a few minutes old. I suspect that you happend to try while that repo was being updated. It happens. Try running `sudo apt update` again.

Comment: I believe there are issues with that repository at the moment ,and Canonical admins are looking into it